# How to handle an activity that calls AsyncTask after going back from other app in Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-asynctask

My Scenario is like this

Activity -> clicked a button that will open other app (for example Facebook app-> loading -> gets data -> passing back to activity -> go back to the activity and call AsyncTask.

In my `AsyncTask`, I call `onPreExecute` to show a dialog, but after going back from other apps it doesn't proceed to show`dialog` and instead of finishing the `AsyncTask`it goes to 'onDetachedFromWindow' and crashes. I'm wondering why and how can I solve this?

I'm having an error like this when it crashes
`FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@41fb6a60 is not valid; is your activity running?`

Here is my `onActivityResult()` in my `Activity`

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.e(TAG, "I'm in onActivity " + resultCode);
    if (requestCode == Constants.FACEBOOK_AUTH_RESULT_CODE) {
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private class LoginDialogListener implements Facebook.DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        Log.d(TAG, "LoginONComplete");
        String token = facebook.getAccessToken();
        long token_expires = facebook.getAccessExpires();
        Log.d(TAG, "AccessToken: " + token);
        Log.d(TAG, "AccessExpires: " + token_expires);

        if (isPublishStreamAuthorized()) {
            facebookSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            facebookSharedPreferences
                    .edit()
                    .putLong(Constants.FACEBOOK_ACCESS_EXPIRES,
                            token_expires).commit();
            facebookSharedPreferences.edit()
                    .putString(Constants.FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN, token)
                    .commit();
            facebookAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
        } else {
            logoutFacebook();
        }

    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Constants.NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnCancel");
        logoutFacebook();
    }
}

private class IDRequestListener implements AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener {
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "IDRequestONComplete");
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);

            id = json.getString("id");
            fname = json.getString("first_name");
            lname = json.getString("last_name");
            email = json.getString("email");
            name = json.getString("name");
            gender = json.getString("gender");
            locale = json.getString("locale");
            verified = json.getString("verified");

            // check if email is null
            if(email == null) {
                email = "";
            }

            LoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Utils.setFacebookUser(context, name, id);
                    saveUserFBDetailsTask
                            = new SaveUserFBDetailsAsyncTask(id, fname, lname, email, name,
                            gender, locale, verified);
                    saveUserFBDetailsTask.execute();
                    /*
                    * String fbId, String fbFName, String fbLName, String email,
                                      String fbName, String gender, String locale, String verified
                    * */
                }
            });
        }

        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                                        Object state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                                        Object state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here is my AsyncTask inside my activity

```
    class SaveUserFBDetailsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String fbId, fbFName, fbLName, email, fbName, gender,
            locale, verified,
            result, errorCode, message, userId, cards, response;
    private JSONObject returnData;

    public SaveUserFBDetailsAsyncTask(String fbId, String fbFName, String fbLName, String email,
                                      String fbName, String gender, String locale, String verified) {
        this.fbId = fbId;
        this.fbFName = fbFName;
        this.fbLName = fbLName;
        this.email = email;
        this.fbName = fbName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.locale = locale;
        this.verified = verified;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
          progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show(); 
    }
```

Here is my `Facebook.java`

```
public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
        int activityCode, final DialogListener listener) {

    boolean singleSignOnStarted = false;

    mAuthDialogListener = listener;

    // Prefer single sign-on, where available.
    if (activityCode >= 0) {
        singleSignOnStarted = startSingleSignOn(activity, mAppId,
                permissions, activityCode);
    }
    // Otherwise fall back to traditional dialog.
    if (!singleSignOnStarted) {
        startDialogAuth(activity, permissions);
    }
}

public void authorizeCallback(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == mAuthActivityCode) {

        // Successfully redirected.
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            // Check OAuth 2.0/2.10 error code.
            String error = data.getStringExtra("error");
            if (error == null) {
                error = data.getStringExtra("error_type");
            }

            // A Facebook error occurred.
            if (error != null) {
                if (error.equals(SINGLE_SIGN_ON_DISABLED)
                        || error.equals("AndroidAuthKillSwitchException")) {
                    Util.logd("Facebook-authorize", "Hosted auth currently "
                        + "disabled. Retrying dialog auth...");
                    startDialogAuth(mAuthActivity, mAuthPermissions);
                } else if (error.equals("access_denied")
                        || error.equals("OAuthAccessDeniedException")) {
                    Util.logd("Facebook-authorize", "Login canceled by user.");
                    mAuthDialogListener.onCancel();
                } else {
                    String description = data.getStringExtra("error_description");
                    if (description != null) {
                        error = error + ":" + description;
                    }
                    Util.logd("Facebook-authorize", "Login failed: " + error);
                    mAuthDialogListener.onFacebookError(
                      new FacebookError(error));
                }

            // No errors.
            } else {
                setAccessToken(data.getStringExtra(TOKEN));
                setAccessExpiresIn(data.getStringExtra(EXPIRES));
                if (isSessionValid()) {
                    Util.logd("Facebook-authorize",
                            "Login Success! access_token="
                                    + getAccessToken() + " expires="
                                    + getAccessExpires());
                    mAuthDialogListener.onComplete(data.getExtras());
                } else {
                    mAuthDialogListener.onFacebookError(new FacebookError(
                                    "Failed to receive access token."));
                }
            }

        // An error occurred before we could be redirected.
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

            // An Android error occurred.
            if (data != null) {
                Util.logd("Facebook-authorize",
                        "Login failed: " + data.getStringExtra("error"));
                mAuthDialogListener.onError(
                        new DialogError(
                                data.getStringExtra("error"),
                                data.getIntExtra("error_code", -1),
                                data.getStringExtra("failing_url")));

            // User pressed the 'back' button.
            } else {
                Util.logd("Facebook-authorize", "Login canceled by user.");
                mAuthDialogListener.onCancel();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code plz

Comment: Try starting the another application with `startActivityForResult` and when you get back to your point of origin it should execute `onActivityResult` where you can according to `resultCode` open the dialog from the activity and lunch `asynctask`. My guess is, it wont open dialog cause it needs an activity context, it requires style.

Comment: @parohy can you provide me an example? Thank you. I think also that maybe it destroys my activity.

Comment: i tried using `startActivityForResult` but it doesn't call the AsyncTask

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa i added my code

Comment: this is not the latest version of FB sdk, why arent you using the latest sdk ?

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa i needed to use this to avoid big changes to the code.

Comment: why dont you try to call your asynctask in onresume method

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan I tried but it still crashes and give the same error

Comment: Donr open dialog from `AsyncTask`. That is a different thread than the `Activity` is running on. Open the dialog in `onResume` and start task separately

Comment: it looks like when I go to the `facebook app` then return to my app my `Activity` is destroyed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used the latest Facebook SDK to solve it.